# What is the length limit of the HTML META tags?

Tags: html, metadata, constraints

And how do the constraints differ in practice on various browsers?

Comment: Just what are you trying to do with meta tags that make you concerned about a size limit?

Comment: There is no length limit. What exactly do you worry about?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Meta Description Tag Length: It’s not
>   the number of words that count. It’s
>   actually the number of characters
>   length. Because, Google will cut off
>   anything more than 155(roughly)
>   characters. Optimizing for in the
>   description and try to limit its
>   length to 25-30 words. Also try to use
>   no more than two sentences.

Taken from http://online-seo-information.blogspot.com/2009/01/meta-description-tag-length-examples.html

Comment: 155 is the lenght of the snippet that appears in the search results. The meta description, searched by Google can be as long as you won't. Google says "the more information you give us, the better your search result snippet can be".

Comment: I just did a Google search for "google seo meta description". The length of the SERP snippets for the top 10 results are: 150, 164, 161, 152, 229, 141, 124, 140, 143, and 123. I did not include the final space and ellipsis for the truncated results. Stating some arbitrary length limit (155) is probably not good advice. I was surprised to see that 229 length in the #5 spot. I would say the longer the better. Give Google more information as long as that information is high quality and unique. On the other hand, if 80 characters is sufficient to accurately describe your document, then 80 it is!

Answer (score 4):

I think the general view is that if you think the length of your META tag might be too long, then it IS too long!

For keywords and description tags I realized some folks want to stuff every possible term they can think of in there but its a lost cause.  The content of your site will get you ranked in Google and similar much better than spamming the META tags.

[How Google uses Meta tags](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812) which describes using a short description... and Google doesn't even look at the "keywords" tag. (which is typically the one SEO trigger happy marketing folks stuff full of crud)

Answer (score 4):

The limit is *More like 265 characters*, as *Aviva Blumstein* found out in an experiment she carried out and published under the title [Tested: The Best Length for a Description Tag is Longer Than You Think](http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/meta-description-length-google-2011.html) in 9/2011. While it is true that the *snippets* shown are cut down to a little less than 160 characters (looks like "at the closest word boundary before 160 chars are reached"), the entire description is used *for display*, but only the first ~265 characters are really searched for the keyword specified.

Doing a little math, I come out at a maximum useful length of `265 + 160 - lastword_length` (as the last word ending *before* reaching the 165<sup>th</sup> character is the last one searched for the keyword), which makes **roughly 400 characters** (425 minus that "last word", including some "tolerance" as you probably don't want to count precisely where the boundary will run).

So while the **keywords** you want to be found should be **within the first 265 characters**, you can extend your meta-desc beyond that limit.

Answer (score 2):

Ideal character/ words limit in google of title = 66 and in yahoo = 120
Meta-Description = 150 to 160 Characters

Answer (score 1):

The w3c makes no mention of size limits [meta at w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.2).  As for browser implementations, you would need to look at the individual browser's source code and/or documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Meta limits for Title max. 65char and for Description 160char

Answer (score -2):

Search engines generally truncate snippets longer than 160 character

Comment: Do you have any source for this assertion and why it is any different from [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1172309/215552)?